# Как сделать чат на java(Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Как сделать просто чат я плюс минус понимаю. Создаются папки в firebase database и пользователи пишут друг другу по uid. А как сделать так чтобы пользователь без регистрации могли писать друг другу но при этом поиск доступных пользователей ведётся из определенных папок. Как это реализовать или без регистрации никак?